# Doctrine Inheritance Mapping

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have Vehicle and Person classes. I have items that can be assigned to EITHER a person or a vehicle. I looked into inheritance mapping and I am visualizing my assignment table to be the one that would use the inheritance mapping but I'm not sure if I am correct. I would expect my assignment table to look like:

```
ID   |   item_id  |  type (vehicle/person) | entityId (the ID of the vehicle or person)
____ |____________|________________________|_____________________________________________
1    |     1      |      person            |       1
2    |     2      |      vehicle           |       1
```

Can someone explain the correct mapping to use and maybe an example?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have an `items` table and then two more tables for each?  Such as `person_item` and `vehicle_item` ?  I don't think it makes sense to use inheritance for person/vehicle unless they share a lot of the same common attributes or are logically similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance mapping is for when you have (for example) an Address which could be a Person Address vs. a Business Address.  You can have a doctrine Superclass `Address` that `PersonAddress` and `BusinessAddress` inherits from. [Doctrine Superclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) This isn't the proper approach for your situation.

The proper solution would be to make a `ManyToMany` (Many people have many items) association from `Person` to `Item` and `ManyToMany` (Many vehicles have many items) from `Vehicle` to `Item`.  If you don't want and item assigned to both a person and a vehicle, you'll have to work that logic into your controllers.

It's possible to have your `Item` be sort of the primary object with associations to either a person or vehicle and include the object type.  This can and does work, yet it really complicates your application significantly. I've modeled a current project in that fashion, but I had good reason to go that route.